# Validar ingreso de datos en Python (soy novato)

Tags: python, validación

Muy buenas quisiera ver si me podrían ayudar, se trata de que si el usuario no pone absolutamente nada y le da <kbd>Enter</kbd> me sale error, este es mi programa (algo rustico lo se pero me funciona)

```
h = int(input("Introduzca numero para que se repita: "))
while h > 8 or h == 7:
    print("pon menos que 8 y diferente que 7")
    h = int(input("vuelve a introducir: "))
if h <= 6 and h !=3:
    print("Muchas gracias")
elif h == 3:
    for i in range (3):
        print(h)
```

Yo deseo que al momento que te pida introducir un numero y el usuario no ponga nada y le de <kbd>Enter</kbd> me muestre algo como "Pon algo" (Estoy practicando Python <3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías utilizar un *while* y capturar el error con un *try*, de esta manera podrás solicitar que se ingrese un número incluso si se ingresan letras o vacios.

Te adjunto el ejemplo:

```
h = 0
while not h: # Valida que h tenga algún valor (Mientras no lo tenga seguimos iterando)
    try: # Capturamos el error en el caso de que se ingrese alguna letra o un vacio
        h = int(input("Introduzca numero para que se repita: "))
    except: # Si se ingresa un valor que no es un número igualamos h a 0 para que itere nuevamente
        h = 0
while h > 8 or h == 7:
    print("pon menos que 8 y diferente que 7")
    h = int(input("vuelve a introducir: "))
if h <= 6 and h !=3:
    print("Muchas gracias")
elif h == 3:
    for i in range (3):
        print(h)
```

Espero sea de ayuda. Saludos ;)

Answer (score 0):

facilmente le puedes agregar un if de esta manera:

```py
h = int(input("Introduzca numero para que se repita: "))
if h:
   while h > 8 or h == 7:
        print("pon menos que 8 y diferente que 7")
        h = int(input("vuelve a introducir: "))
   if h <= 6 and h !=3:
        print("Muchas gracias")
   elif h == 3:
        for i in range (3):
        print(h)
else:
   print("Pon algo")
```

de tal manera validas que si o si ingrese un valor en la variable `h`.